# Operator Overloading and LNK2019 error in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading

I'm writing a Point class which holds three floats, x y z, some functions and overloaded operators. I coded operators in the following form:

```
inline Point Point::operator+ (Point point)
{
    return Point(x + point.x, y + point.y, z + point.z);
}

inline void Point::operator+= (Point point)
{
   x += point.x;
   y += point.y;
   z += point.z;
}
```

Is this the right way to overload these operators? I've tested it and it works but I've seen another form like so:

```
inline Point& Point::operator+ (Point& point)
{
    return Point(x + point.x, y + point.y, z + point.z);
}

inline Point& Point::operator+= (Point& point)
{
    x += point.x;
    y += point.y;
    z += point.z;
        return *this;
}
```

What is the difference between the two forms?

Also I can use the operators inside my Point.cpp file but if I try to use it say in Main.cpp, I get a lnk2019 error for unresolved external symbol. Oddly, my functions work outside the defining file. What am I missing to get these operators to work outside the file they're defined in?

Comment: To avoid the link error, I guess you could try not declaring them inline. Though I wouldn't actually expect that to be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The first operator should be

```
inline Point Point::operator+ (const Point &point) const
{
    return Point(x + point.x, y + point.y, z + point.z);
}
```

it shouldn't return a reference because its excepted to construct a new object and not modify a existing one (a general rule of thumb). const is added to the function because the point its called one shouldn't be modified. a reference to the point as argument is added so there won't be unnecessary copy

The second one should be

```
inline Point& Point::operator+= (const Point& point)
{
    x += point.x;
    y += point.y;
    z += point.z;
    return *this;
}
```

because it supposed to modify an existing point, so it should return a reference. const is added to the argument because it shouldn't be changed. the function itself is not const because it should modify the point itself.

The linker error you get is because of the inline. either provide full implementation in header file, or remove the inline.

Comment: And add a `const` to the return value of `operator+`.

Comment: @EricZ: why? then things like `Point result = p1 + p2;` won't work

Comment: Wrong. `Point result = p1 + p2` is copy by value and it works. `const` is there to prevent `p1 + p2 = result` or calling non-const member functions on `p1 + p2`.

Comment: @EricZ: `p1 + p2 = result` shouldn't be possible since the return value is a temporary, just like `3 = my_int` is not possible.

Comment: For user-defined types, it is possible.

Comment: @EricZ: like defining a `Point::operator =(Point) const`? why would such a thing exist, and ever if there is a reason for it, why would `a + b = c` be guarded from it?

Comment: In a shot, you don't want the resulting `a+b` be modified, do you? It doesn't really matter it'll be modified via explicit assignment or a non-const member function. The rule is, if you don't want that happen, return a const. That's exactly what an intrinsic type does.

Answer (score 2):

```
inline Point& Point::operator+ (Point& point)
{
    return Point(x + point.x, y + point.y, z + point.z);
}
```

That's wrong, its returning a reference to a temporary that no longer exists when the function returns. It would result in a segfault if you are lucky enough. Most compilers will give you a warning if you try to do it. Ideally you would write this operator as a free function, implemented in terms of your member `operator+=`.

```
inline Point& Point::operator+= (Point& point)
{
    x += point.x;
    y += point.y;
    z += point.z;
        return *this;
}
```

This is pretty much the preferred way, except that you should be taking the `point` as a const reference, otherwise you cannot use it with temporaries. Returning a reference to itself is what allows chaining operators. It's generally said that when in doubt, do as the ints, and the ints do that.

Summing up, the 'cannonical' implementation would be:

```
inline Point& Point::operator+=( Point const& point )
{
    x += point.x;
    y += point.y;
    z += point.z;
    return *this;
}

inline Point const operator+( Point left, Point const& right )
{
     return left += right;
}
```

Note that the having `operator+` be a free function allows conversions to `Point` to happen at both operands and not just the right one. It's conveniently implemented in terms of `operator+=`: The left argument is taken by value in order to have a temporary copy that we can modify, and we do so by adding the right argument to it. Since `operator+=` returns a reference, we use such return in order to provide the value that would be copied as the function result.

Comment: I would prefer member version of `operator+` as `Point` class doesn't seem to have a converting constructor anyway. Besides, it should return a `const Point` to be consistent w/ build-in types.

Comment: @Eric Z: Added the `const`. Even if `Point` class does not have converting constructors, there is always the chance that another class decides to provide a conversion operator to it. And since its independent of the class itself, and expressed in terms of the class interface, its better to decouple it and make it a free function.

Comment: +1: oh. If that's the case, putting it as a non-member function makes sense as `operator+` should be communicative.

Comment: @Eric Z: You mean commutative. It's so for the `int`s, and for `Points`. It's not for `std::string` but I would still declare it as a free function, otherwise `str + "b"` would work but `"a" + str` would not.